# How to find out a wordpress taxonomy ID? ...not term ID

Tags: wordpress

How can I find out the wordpress taxonomy ID?

I want to create a term exists query...

```
if (term_exists(array(

     'term_id'              => 4,
     'term_taxonomy_ID'     => x

)))
```

But I can't figure out how to find out the ID for my taxonomy called: 'file-formats'

Any help would be awesome thanks.

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'file-formats' );
if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term_name ) {
        echo $term_name->term_id."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already, but this returns the term ID, I need to find out the ID of my taxonomy. My taxonomy is called 'file-format', but I need the ID of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies
or
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

Try this:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'taxonomy-name' );
if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->term_id.'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I think I accidentally edited you edited your response, dunno how that happened. I'm not quite sure if you understand what I'm after. I just need find out the ID of my taxonomy so I can finish my query. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists

Because I can't seem to get this to work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617533/wordpress-term-exist-not-echoing-anything

So my last try is to use the 'term_taxonomy_ID' instead of 'term_taxonomy', which I don't think works, but I can't personally figure out how to assign my taxonomy group to the query

Comment: This just returns my term? Am I getting confused with terms and taxonomies. I though a term was within a taxonomy group